# Increase Root Partition Size

Tags: partitioning, root, disk

I want to increase size of my root partition `/dev/sda1` but I'm not able to do so either with GParted or with Terminal.

1. On Terminal It gives the following error:

   > The filesystem is already 4718592 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
2. On GParted it doesn't give me any option to increase the disk size.
3. Use Gparted Live same result as Point 2

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have to move your swap partition to the end of the extended partition, shrink and move the extended partition, then expand the Ubuntu partition.  You can't extend when the free space is not next to the partition you want to expand.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do does not work from within a running system ... so follow these steps :

- Boot from a GParted Live media, either GParted Live or Ubuntu Live media.
- Right click the `swap` partition and select **swap off** in case it is mounted.
- As there is no data on `sda2` and `sda5`, first delete `sda5` and then `sda2`.
- Resize `sda1`, right click the partition and select **Resize/Move** to increase it.
- Now create a new `linux-swap` partition from the unallocated free space.

You have to update the UUIDs of the partitions in the `/etc/fstab` file afterwards.

Open a terminal and execute : `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

To correct the UUID entries in the fstab file execute : `sudo blkid`

Open another terminal and execute : `sudo gedit /mnt/etc/fstab`

Replace the UUID entries of `sda1` (in case it is different) and `sda2`

(with those entries of the output given from the `blkid` command).

Shutdown, remove the Live media and boot the operating system ...